# Post form from localhost to a domain

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, forms

I have a form that always will be running on localhost, and in this case it will be a loginform. It should send a username and a password to the other domain (that runs MySQL and PHP) that will do all the basic stuff, check username and password agains the usertable and so on... and return true/false to the localhost. On localhost i can only run html, javascript and all that basic client-side stuff. Sure, there is some jquery-stuff for this but in this case I want to keep the code to a minimum and wanna build it all mostly for learning.

I've searched here and on google but havent found any concrete info. Any idéas where to start?  Send the login stuff thru GET does not feel right due to security reasons, but in the other case; is this possible doing secure at all? Maybe the best way is to generate a iframe with a loginform from the server side to the client?

Every comment is useful!

Comment: The best way I can think of to do this is through AJAX. It is recommended to read up on that before you start. That will allow you to fetch the output of your remote PHP script into your localhost.

Comment: Yep, ajax is the plan. But i can't find any useful info regarding cross domain (localhost / web hotel). Localhost sends two strings to the server side, the server side will do all the authentication stuff and send some cookies and yada yada if true and return a json result to localhost. That's more what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

try to send the data as jquery ajax request and remember to make the type as post not get since the default is get ..

another thing to notice is that you have to enable the crossdomain request in your ajax request since your sending post data to another host ..

check this [api for jquery ajax request](http://s.zah.me/wwCip8)

Comment: Thanks! But, this was jQuery. :) We're trying to avoid stuff like that. Mostly for education purposes.

Comment: unless your using server side language you will have to use the ajax methods in javascript, and the best is to use jq .. and this is my idea

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no secure method to do login with javascript only. You can use jquery to check the username and password but every one can maipulate the results and with no user and passwords to login.

Comment: Nope, of course this is true. But it's not loclhost only. The localhost just posts a username and a password to the server side and all the secure stuff is handled there and will send some cookies with rendom checkstrings and stuff if true and all basic stuff like that, the question is how to send two strings to the server side and get a true/false in return (as like json formatted data).